# check if string includes other characters besides the type you want python

Tags: python, boolean

I want to be able to return a boolean value if there are any other characters that deem false. Ex.

```
x = "0&"
if x.isnumeric() == False:
     return "not a number"
else:
     return "is a number"
```

Even though there's a number in there, i want it to return false if there are any **other** character that is **not** a number. So i want it to return True if "06" (just an example), and False if "3@"(another example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x="8R"    
if x.isnumeric():
     print("True")
else:
     print("False")
```

This code should print out false